# How to print only first few items in slightly?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I have 10 items in list. I want  to print only first 5 items in the list. How to add condition using data-sly-list

Comment: Personally, I'd say don't do it in HTL (Sightly). Sightly is not meant for "business logic". It is meant to display something. So if you wanted to only display 5 items from your list, then use a (Sling) model and only return a List with 5 items to the HTL template.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `index` or `count` [properties of the list item](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list) with data-`sly-test` like:

```
<ul data-sly-list="${mylist}">
    <li data-sly-test="${itemList.index < 5}">${itemList}</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, if your list is big and you do not want to iterate it, you could define an Use-API helper that creates a new list with just the first 5 needed elements.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think this will iterate the whole list but only display the first 5 items. What if the list has 100.000 items and all of them are iterated to display just 5 of them?

Comment: That's correct @Jens, to limit the size effectively someone would need to write an Use-API helper that creates a new list with target size.

Comment: @Jens in my experience, it's better to avoid having any logic in HTL that isn't strictly presentation logic. Filtering a set of items should be handled by Java code where you have a lot more control over the data.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I totally agree and that's what I wrote as a comment to the question.